# Grid view Column headers based on results from another table vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Suppose I have a table with columns userdef1, userdef2 .....userdef6 and I have another table that defines these fields. i.e UserDef1 = "MyName" etc

What would be the best approach for  retrieving these values and updating the column headers?

Comment: You should show us the model of both tables. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is use the RowDataBound event.

In that event you can fill each column, including the Headers.

```
With e.Row
   if .RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
      'do the logic here

   end If
```